# Escape spaces in Bash folder variable

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I am trying to create a variable in Bash to access fastly to some folders and save it to my bash_profile script file. This is how script looks like

```
Documents=~/Documents
Apps=~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications
```

After running the script the $Documents variable works and $Apps doesn't. It tells:

```
-bash: cd: /Users/myusername/Library/Application: No such file or directory
```

This is the path to the folder:

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications
```

How should I escape spaces? I use Vim and I type "cd $Apps".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spaces are fine; it's your command that's wrong.

```
cd "$Apps"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also quote the string and not use the backslash character:
    Apps='~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications'
    cd "$Apps"